# Unit test coverage report through Sonar Runner installed on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I am using Jenkins for building my maven project and invoking a standalone sonar analysis which generates the sonar report.
But I am not able to generate the unit test coverage report
Note: i have Sonar Runner installed on my Jenkins instance.

Please Help.
My sonar properties are:

```
sonar.projectKey=XXX  
sonar.projectName=YYY  
sonar.sources={Path to Source Code}  
sonar.binaries={Path to Binaries}  
sonar.forceAnalysis=true  
sonar.login={username}  
sonar.password=${Masked_Password}
```

I have jacoco plugn installed on SONAR. And when i run the sonar analysis,it says

```
05:47:06.942 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...    
05:47:06.947 INFO  o.s.p.j.JaCoCoPlugin - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /workspace/XXX/target/jacoco.exec 
05:47:07.897 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 955 ms
```

I have read at places that sonar runner does not runs unit test or shows unit-test coverage report. Is it true? If yes, is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're building your project with Maven, why do you try to run a Sonar analysis with the Sonar Runner whereas you can do it as a PostBuild action with Maven? This requires almost no configuration.

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+Sonar+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonaronJenkinsJob-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswithMaven

Comment: Thanks for your response Fabrice:)...I'm generating sonar reports for many modules separately,hence have more freedom to configure each job separately in terms of project name,project details etc if I use sonar runner(hope I'm correct:) ). I know, if I provide the path to test reports,it will reuse the reports...But I'm not sure,where the test reports are being stored. Please Help.

Comment: My project is a maven project. So do i need to add plugins to maven for executing the unit test and store the reports which i can use with sonar runner?

Comment: No and yes :) No, you just have to configure the surefire plugin to generate XML reports. And yes, you have to add the JaCoCo plugin and configure it to generate "jacoco.exec" report.

Comment: So, first I need to have surefire plugin installed in maven for XML reports to be generated?

Comment: Not "installed", but "configured" yes.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam, [please have a look at this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267948/sonarqube-test-coverage-report-for-android-built-with-ant) I've also tried Jacoco inside an Ant generated build script for this project to no avail so far... I understand that maven is probably the easy way out but it's not trivial to switch ATM.